# Netstat -b shows open connections for an old (not used) project from totally unrelated apps

Tags: windows, netstat

See screenshot below:

[image: netstat -b]

In `netstat -b` output I always see open connections to an old project I developed 2 years ago. They also show when I open new applications (you see totally unrelated apps listening to the connection, like `viber`). How do I get rid of these "ghost" (to me) connections and why does this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked in Task Viewer that the designated `.exe` is truly not running?

Comment: @harrymc Thx, the .exe apps are running but the connection and app was a 2-years old project which is not even related to that. For example, I run JetBrains Rider and a connection appears for the app (which used to be a web app, created inside webstorm, nothing to do with Rider). You also see "VIBER" in the apps that supposedly open that connection!!

Comment: Use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to find out where they're starting from, and eradicate them from their folders and from starting.